# Hibernate Search Configuration Problems

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm very new to Hibernate Search and trying to integrate it with my application.
Facing a memory leak issue (threads going into wait/park state).

Hibernate Search configuration (very minimal) is annotation driven. Using :

```
@Indexed(index = "<index_name>")
@IndexedEmbedded
```

AND

```
@Field(name = "title", store = Store.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "standardAnalyzer")
```

Hibernate Search properties:

```
<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="../lucene/indexes" />
<property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem" /> 
<property name="hibernate.search.default.exclusive_index_use"
            value="false" />
```

Using Tomcat 8 to deploy the application.

My main problem is that

**VisualVm clearly shows that  Hibernate search creates a sync consumer thread for every index. It does so for each and every call I make to my server (in my case, 2 new threads spawned and in parked state on every call). Eventually the number of threads increase till my server becomes unresponsive.**

On server shutdown, i get the error:

> 09-Aug-2017 17:15:28.151 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [procurewise] appears to have started a thread named [Hibernate Search sync consumer thread for index Category] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
> sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
> java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:338)
> org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor.parkCurrentThread(SyncWorkProcessor.java:175)
> org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor.access$300(SyncWorkProcessor.java:35)
> org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.run(SyncWorkProcessor.java:147)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I'm using Spring, Hibernate, JPA, AOP and JAX-RS, Jersey .

Environment Details:

> Hibernate version 5.2.10.Final
>
> Hibernate Search version 5.7.0.Final
>
> Spring version 4.3.6.RELEASE
>
> JPA 2.1
>
> JAVA 8
>
> Jersey 1.8

Comment: This is unrelated, but you should not use `hibernate.search.default.exclusive_index_use` unless you really know why you need it. Really. Also, what version of Hibernate Search are you using?

Comment: @YoannRodière. I've added the Hibernate search version I'm using. Also the exclusive_index_use property was an attempt to stop using locks assuming the MassIndexer spawns multiple threads, which i thought was the issue here. But point noted.

Answer (score 0):

This thread should stop automatically when Hibernate Search shuts down, which happens automatically when Hibernate ORM shuts down.

I see two reasons for this warning: either Tomcat checked the threads while Hibernate ORM was still shutting down, or you didn't stop Hibernate ORM at all.

I would suggest to check your shutdown process, see if Hibernate ORM is closed correctly (normally you use `org.hibernate.SessionFactory.close()`, but I'd expect Spring to take care of that itself), and if it is, see if it's closed synchronously (so that your Tomcat will only perform checks after all the closing is done).

Comment: My problem here is not the warning/error that tomcat gives on shutdown. The problem is that for every call, 2 new threads are spawned and put in the parked state. Over time there are so many threads that my server becomes unresponsive. Is it

Comment: @HarshvardhanDudeja From what you're telling me, it seems as though you are creating a Hibernate ORM SessionFactory for each call to your server, and are not even closing it. Which is really, really bad regardless of whether you're using Hibernate Search or not. You should check your Hibernate ORM/JPA configuration, especially how you configured persistence-related beans and how you are fetching the EntityManager/Session.

Comment: As i mentioned the configuration is Annotation driven. I'm using @PersistenceContext to autowire the entity manager. The JPA configuration contains nothing but a couple of Hibernate properties(eg. show-sql) . Just to mention I'm using Spring Servlet as a bridge to integrate Spring and jersey. I'll update the Question as well